PopART (Population Analysis with Reticulate Trees) crashes on Mac Sonoma
Lately, PopART (Population Analysis with Reticulate Trees; https://popart.maths.otago.ac.nz/) causes my 16GB Macbook Pro to run out of memory, despite files being relatively small. I believe it used to work OK some years back.
Has anyone had the same experience and know a solution?
Thanks

No but PopArt is an old program and the error is more likely incompatibility with e.g. Sonoma as the current OSX version than a memory error.
